How does Self-Scaling Fast Givens QR work for (Regularized) Linear Least Squares
Basic Problem
I need help to understand the Self-Scaling Fast Givens QR decomposition proposed in
Anda A. A. & Park H., Self-Scaling Fast Rotations for Stiff and Equality Constrained Linear Least Squares Problems (currently available via this link)
that I want to apply it for Regularized Least Squares Problem. I tried multiple related methods and got them working, but I need to improve the runtime. Therefore, I wanted to try the mentioned algorithm.
What I don't understand about it is:

how are the involved diagonal matrices $\mathbf{D}$ and $\mathbf{D}'$ accessed and updated during the iterations?
how do the rotation operations have to be chained?
how is the matrix $\mathbf{Q}$ - which is never stored explicitly - applied to the right-hand side without the use of square roots?

I found this question hard to formulate, so I highly appreciate feedback on how to improve the question itself.
Where does it come from?
To solve a Weighted Tikhonov-regularized Least Square Problem for deconvolution, the system
$\mathbf{A}\mathbf{\hat{y}}=\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{y}\\\mathbf{0}\end{bmatrix}$
has to be solved for $\mathbf{\hat{y}}$ in the Least Squares sense. The left-hand side matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is given by
$
\begin{bmatrix}
\sqrt{\mathbf{W}}\cdot\mathbf{K}\\ 
\sqrt{\lambda}\cdot\mathbf{P}
\end{bmatrix}
$
with a diagonal weight matrix $\mathbf{W}$, a convolution matrix $\mathbf{K}$, a regularization parameter (penalty weight) $\lambda$, and a finite difference matrix $\mathbf{P}$ for the computation of $p$-th order forward finite differences.
I wanted to solve this problem via $QR$-decomposition because $\mathbf{K}$ encodes the convolution with a truncated Gaussian peak and thus the condition number of $\mathbf{A}^{T}\cdot\mathbf{A}$ easily grows to an extent that prohibits the use of normal equations for the appropriate choice of $\lambda$ (has to be chosen too high for the system to be solvable, so the solution is meaningless). I'm also interested in the log determinant of $\mathbf{A}^T\cdot\mathbf{A}$, so a triangular factorization seems like a good choice.
Both $\mathbf{K}$ of shape $m\times n$ and $\mathbf{P}$ of shape $\left(m-p+1\right)\times n$ are sparse with a banded structure, e.g.,
$
\mathbf{K}=\begin{bmatrix}
k_{0}&k_{1}&k_{2}&k_{1}&k_{0}&0&0&0&\cdots&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\ 
0&k_{0}&k_{1}&k_{2}&k_{1}&k_{0}&0&0&\cdots&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&k_{0}&k_{1}&k_{2}&k_{1}&k_{0}&0&\cdots&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&k_{0}&k_{1}&k_{2}&k_{1}&k_{0}&\cdots&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&\cdots&k_{0}&k_{1}&k_{2}&k_{1}&k_{0}&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&\cdots&0&k_{0}&k_{1}&k_{2}&k_{1}&k_{0}&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&\cdots&0&0&k_{0}&k_{1}&k_{2}&k_{1}&k_{0}&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&\cdots&0&0&0&k_{0}&k_{1}&k_{2}&k_{1}&k_{0}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$
$
\mathbf{P}=\begin{bmatrix}
1&-2&1&0&0&\cdots&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&-2&1&0&\cdots&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&-2&1&\cdots&0&0&0&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&0&0&\cdots&1&-2&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&\cdots&0&1&-2&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&\cdots&0&0&1&-2&1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$
when boundary effects are not considered. $\mathbf{K}$ may have way larger bandwidths.
Edit
The system does not have a full Toeplitz structure after the boundaries were considered, but the banded structure persists to an extent that a $QR$-decomposition keeps the banded structure with only a few boundary columns to be considered in a special way. I managed this already. Also, the weight matrix ruins the Toeplitz structure anyway.
What other methods I have tried already could did the trick
Given the banded structure, Householder transformations did not seem appropriate to me, so I tried the LSQR algorithm in
Paige C. C. & Saunders M. A., LSQR: An Algorithm for Sparse Linear Equations and Sparse Least Squares, ACM Transactions on Mathematical SoftwareVolume 8, Issue 1, pp 43–71 (currently available via this link)
which uses only matrix-vector multiplication which can be formulated efficiently for the problem as a combination of 2 convolution operations. However, convergence is too slow and I also would be interested in computing the log determinant of $\mathbf{A}^T\cdot\mathbf{A}$, but I don't know if and how this can be retrieved from this iterative solver.
After deciding for direct methods, I already managed to solve the problem via the G2B-$QR$-decomposition proposed in
Eldén L., An Algorithm for the Regularization of Ill-Conditioned, Banded Least Squares Problems, SIAM Journal on Scientific and Statistical Computing, Vol. 5, Iss. 1 (1984) (currently available here).
The publication is behind a paywall, but this is not important. In a nuthsell, it uses Givens rotations for $QR$-decomposition. It has a simple row pivoting strategy that reduces fill-in to the minimum extent possible.
Efficient $QR$ - where I need help
With standard Givens rotations, the G2B-$QR$-decomposition is a bit too slow as well because the square roots for the trigonometric functions for the plane rotations and vector copies dominate the runtime. The matrices are too narrow-banded and the relative time for computing the coefficients $c$ and $s$ for the rotation matrix
$
\mathbf{G}=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&\cdots&0&\cdots&0&\cdots&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&\cdots&0&\cdots&0&\cdots&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&\cdots&0&\cdots&0&\cdots&0&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\cdots&c&\cdots&-s&\cdots&0&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\cdots&s&\cdots&c&\cdots&0&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\cdots&0&\cdots&0&\cdots&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&\cdots&0&\cdots&0&\cdots&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&\cdots&0&\cdots&0&\cdots&0&0&1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$
becomes a bottleneck.
The Self-Scaling Fast Givens QR decomposition proposed in
Anda A. A. & Park H., Self-Scaling Fast Rotations for Stiff and Equality Constrained Linear Least Squares Problems (currently available via this link)
can avoid the computation of square roots, reduce the number of multiplications involved, and on top of that avoid vector copies.
For this, a single Givens rotation for annihilation of the leading non-zero element of the lower of 2 rows $\mathbf{X}$ out of $\mathbf{A}$  is re-written as
$\mathbf{G}\cdot\mathbf{X}=\mathbf{G}\cdot\mathbf{D}\cdot\mathbf{Y}=\mathbf{D}'\cdot\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{Y}$
where $\mathbf{D}$ and $\mathbf{D}'$ are $2\times 2$ diagonal matrices and $\mathbf{F}$ is the product of 2 matrices like
$
\mathbf{F}=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
-\alpha&1\\
\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}
1&\beta\\
0&1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$
or similar (to avoid vector copies for the annihilation) and
$
\mathbf{G}=\begin{bmatrix}
c&-s\\
s&c\\
\end{bmatrix}
$.
$\mathbf{D}$ can be initialised as an identity matrix $\mathbf{I}$ or via the weights, so for the Regularized Least Squares Problem described this should be
$
\mathbf{D}=\begin{bmatrix}
\sqrt{\mathbf{W}}\\ 
\sqrt{\lambda}
\end{bmatrix}
$
To avoid the necessity for square roots, $\mathbf{D}^{2}$ and $\mathbf{D}'^{2}$ are stored instead of $\mathbf{D}$ and $\mathbf{D}'$. For keeping the element growth in the diagonal matrices at bay, the following computation strategy is proposed:
Decision table for the Self-Scaling Fast Rotation
Question Part 1
So, this is the point where my confusion starts. In the table it seems like $\mathbf{D}^{2}$ is only accessed for deciding whether to take the left or the right branch of the decisions and pre-factor $\gamma$ computations.
If this is correct, then why not just take $\mathbf{D}=\mathbf{I}$ and only go for the left branch all the time with pre-factors of 1? Is the other initialisation with weights only useful because squaring a weight-based $\mathbf{D}$ avoids square roots of the weights $\mathbf{W}$ and $\lambda$? From what's written there, $\mathbf{D}$ is also never updated because it's apparently only mixed into the product $\mathbf{D}'\cdot\mathbf{F}$. I have problems with understanding this formulation because in
Golub G. H. & Van Loan C. F., Matrix Computations, Third Edition, Chapter 5.2.5
fast Givens rotations are expressed as $\mathbf{Q}=\mathbf{M}\cdot\mathbf{D}^{-\frac{1}{2}}$, so there is only one diagonal matrix involved which was easier to understand.
Question Part 2
How can two rotations be chained given that they have a $\mathbf{D}'_{x}$- and an $\mathbf{F}_{x}$-matrix each ? I don't see that they are commutative so that the individual diagonal matrices could somehow be combined.
Question Part 3
For solving the linear system after the $QR$-decomposition, it is left-multiplied with $\mathbf{Q}^{T}$.
$\mathbf{Q}$ is basically given by chaining the product with the rotation matrices as $\mathbf{G}_{x}\cdots\mathbf{G}_{2}\cdot\mathbf{G}_{1}$, but the product
$
\mathbf{Q}^{T}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{y}\\\mathbf{0}\end{bmatrix}
$
should be computed without forming $\mathbf{Q}$ explicitely to save runtime and memory.
Translated to the Fast Givens rotations, a single rotation is achieved by left-multiplication with $\mathbf{D}'_{x}\cdot\mathbf{F}_{x}$, so one has to keep track of the diagonal entries of the single $\mathbf{D}_{x}'^{2}$-matrices and also the $\alpha$- and $\beta$-values that make up the single $\mathbf{F}_{x}$-matrices together with the branch of the decision table that was taken.
How can the product with $\mathbf{Q}^{T}$ be computed without computing the square roots of $\mathbf{D}'^{2}$? Do they have to be formed or am I overlooking something?
Long story short, I don't see how the single rotations can be applied to the right-hand side to achieve the implicit left-mulitplication with $\mathbf{Q}^T$.
